# OpenSUSE 13.1 openvpn

Tags: dns, routes, dhcp, opensuse, openvpn

So I need to setup a openvpn connection for my work to get access to services etc. I used to work with a OpenSuse Virtual Machine to get things done, but now i set up a vagrant environment (https://github.com/tcdev0/openSUSE-13.1-vagrant-ansible) which provisions a virtual machine (OpenSUSE 13.1) and connects via openvpn to work, which must be done over cli.

I noticed a difference in using the Networkmanager applet for openvpn and manually starting the openvpn connection with

```
     openvpn client.conf
```

or

```
     systemctl start openvpn@client.service
```

Using the applet everything works fine, i can access alles services like checking out repositories from our gitlab server over ssh, but starting the openvpn connection manually i cant do that.

I checked the routes which are added while connecting to vpn

```
     /sbin/route
```

Connection over Networkmanager applet

```
    default         10.128.10.13    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
    10.0.0.0        10.128.10.13    255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
    10.128.10.1     10.128.10.13    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
    10.128.10.13    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
    172.16.63.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eno16777736
    server          172.16.63.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno16777736
```

Manual Connection

```
    default         10.128.10.13    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
    default         172.16.63.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno16777736
    10.0.0.0        10.128.10.13    255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
    10.128.10.1     10.128.10.13    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
    10.128.10.13    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
    128.0.0.0       10.128.10.13    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
    172.16.63.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eno16777736
    server          172.16.63.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno16777736
```

I should say that i did not configure any routes in the applet, all is set to auto.

So the routes differ from each other but why, what does the networkmanager do or what do i have to configure in my client.conf to get the same result?

Thanks

---

***UPDATE***

Thanks for your reply. One thing i noticed while VPN is up:

```
    ifconfig ...

    eno167777 Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0C:29:91:B4:1E  
              inet Adresse: 172.16.63.131  Bcast:172.16.63.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
```

For the **Network manager connection:**

If I do

```
    nslookup gitlab
```

it shows me the correct address

```
   Name:    gitlab
   Address: 10.32.1.1
```

But for the **manual connection:**

```
    nslookup gitlab
```

i got

```
    Server:     172.16.63.2
    Address:    172.16.63.2#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    ...
```

It seems he is asking the wrong dns server or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously there is a problem with the

```
    /etc/resolve.conf
```

Connecting manual via openvpn does not update this file, while the Networkmanager does.

I dont know if there is a better possibility to automatically update the file, but i came up with the following solution.

adding these lines to the client.conf from (https://github.com/gronke/OpenVPN-linux-push)

```
    script-security 2
    up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
    down /etc/openvpn/down.sh
```

and it works ;)